# Is there any difference between quad in math mode and text mode?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices

Is there any difference between  `$a \text{\quad text\quad} b$` and `$a \quad \text{text} \quad b$`? I cannot see the difference as shown in the following figure.

If there is no difference, which one should I use for the sake of best practice?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$a \text{\quad text\quad} b$\\
$a \quad \text{text} \quad b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to use this when solving `$(x-a)(x-b)=0$`. The solution is usually written in `gather*` as follows

```
\begin{gather*}
(x-a)(x-b)=0\\
x-a=0 \quad\text{or}\quad x-b=0\\
x=a \quad\text{or}\quad x=b
\end{gather*}
```

or

```
\begin{gather*}
(x-a)(x-b)=0\\
x-a=0 \text{\quad or\quad} x-b=0\\
x=a \text{\quad or\quad} x=b
\end{gather*}
```

Comment: A third variant to consider would be `$a$\quad text\quad$b$`. It produces the same output as do the first two variants...

Comment: Personal opinion (of a newbie): *You should put the spaces where they belong*. If they are part of the text then put them inside the `\text`, but in your case they are part of the equation's layout, hence they should go outside of `\text`. Also, the `\quad` might be used in other parts of the equation, and having different spaces associated with the same macro may seem odd (in the source and in the output too, probably).

Comment: The accepted answer is subjected to change without notice. I am so sorry for this inconvenience and thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Under normal conditions, using `\quad` inside or outside `\text` gives the same result, as far as the amount of space is concerned. I'm disregarding what happens when `\text` is used in a sub/superscript, for the moment.

TeX maintains *two* current fonts when it's typesetting a math formula: it remembers the font that was current before the formula started and also takes note of the current math family so that math symbols which are given type 7 are typeset using the font corresponding to the current family. Note that the current math family is only saved as a number; this number will be turned into a real font only when the formula is finished and is being converted into a horizontal list.

When an instruction such as `\quad` is found in a formula, it expands to `\hskip1em` as usual and the em is converted into a length by examining the fontdimen 6 parameter of the current *text* font, so the first that was mentioned above. If `\mskip18mu` were used, the em of the font attached to math family 2 would be used; but it's not.

When `\text{text}` is processed in math mode, TeX executes (in a group)

```
\mathchoice
  {\textdef@\displaystyle\f@size{text}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle\f@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle\sf@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle \ssf@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
```

and we're interested in the first and second arguments to `\mathchoice`. The `\firstchoice@false` command is just to avoid executing multiple times commands such as `\label` or `\stepcounter` that can possibly sneak in the argument to `\text`, but it's irrelevant for the problem at hand.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume we're in `\displaystyle` (but for `\textstyle` it would be the same). TeX typesets four boxes, but uses only the one resulting from

```
\textdef@\displaystyle\f@size{text}
```

This is turned into

```
\hbox{{\everymath{\displaystyle}\let\f@size\f@size\selectfont text}}
```

We have to remember that `\f@size`, `\sf@size` and `\ssf@size` expand to the font sizes LaTeX has determined to be the current overall font size (they are 10pt, 7pt, 5pt when the size is `\normalsize` in a 10pt document; they are 12pt, 8pt, 6pt when the size is `\normalsize` in a 12pt document or `\large` in a 10pt document; and so on). In this case the `\let` does nothing, but `\selectfont` is really relevant!

What does it do? It resets the current text font based on the current values of `\f@encoding`, `\f@family`, `\f@series`, `\f@shape`, `\f@size` and `\f@baselineskip`. In this case, since `\f@size` has not changed, the same font that was current outside `\text` is carried over inside it.

As a conclusion, `\quad` will have the same width inside `\text` as it has outside it.

If `\text` is used in a first level subscript, only `\f@size` changes, becoming equivalent to what `\sf@size` was before, so the `\quad` will use the width corresponding to the current text font, but at `\sf@size`.

Of course, using `\quad` outside `\text` has another difference: the argument to `\text` is typeset in a box, so this glue cannot be used as a break point if the formula is inline. (This was remarked by David Carlisle.)

---

Why the example by Przemysław Scherwentke gives different quads? When we do

```
\font\meta=logo10 at 20pt \meta
```

we're overriding the NFSS infrastructure for font selection: `\meta` will become the current text font, but the values of the `\f@...` macros is ***not*** changed. Therefore for the quads in

```
\meta $a \quad\text{META}\quad b$
```

the value corresponding to `\meta` are used (it is the current text font). Conversely, in

```
\meta $a \text{\quad META\quad} b$
```

the determination of 1em happens *after* `\selectfont`, so the font is reset to what it was *before* the `\meta` instruction, because the `\f@...` macros are not updated when issuing `\meta`. Indeed “META” is typeset in the current text font, not using the logo font.

Here's a test.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\font\meta=logo10 at 14.4pt
{\meta $a \quad\text{META}\quad b$}

{\meta $a \quad\mbox{META}\quad b$}

{\meta $a \text{\quad META\quad} b$}

{\meta $a \quad\text{META}\quad b$}

\newcommand{\goodmeta}{%
  \fontencoding{U}%
  \fontfamily{logo}%
  \fontsize{14.4}{14.4}%
  \selectfont}
{\goodmeta $a \quad\text{META}\quad b$}

{\goodmeta $a \quad\mbox{META}\quad b$}

{\goodmeta $a \text{\quad META\quad} b$}

{\goodmeta $a \quad\text{META}\quad b$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can see that in lines 1, 3 and 4 the word “META” is typeset in Computer Modern, while in line 2 it's in the `logo` font (because `\mbox` uses the current font without issuing any `\selectfont` command).

In the other cases, where `\goodmeta` is used, the results are identical.

Answer (score 12):

In LaTeX, the definition of the macro `\quad` (stated in `latex.ltx`) is:

```
\def\quad{\hskip1em\relax}
```

Note that the macro works the same way in both text and math mode. (The macros `\hskip` and `\relax` are TeX "primitive" commands.)

Thus, *as long as* `1em` has the same value in text and math mode -- which will be the case if you're using a common font family and font size for math and text (which, happily, is the case for the MWE you've posted) -- you can use either variant and get the same output. You should thus feel free to use whichever variant feels most natural to you. To me, `\quad\text{or}\quad` seems a bit more natural than `\text{\quad or\quad}` does...

---

*Addendum*: As @PrzemysławScherwentl has demonstrated in a separate answer, it is *possible* -- say, through the use of a PlainTeX-type font-related instruction -- to create a setup in which the value of `1em` is *not* the same in math and text mode. His example thus serves as an important qualifier.

More generally, whenever you use different font families for text and math (possibly even at different sizes), you *will* find that the two variants do not produce the same output.

Comment: You don't have to use primitive font syntax, you'd get the same with any font change that did not reset the math fonts, so most latex font changes. Also you get different behaviour due to boxing, even with no font change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks. I didn't mean to imply that the *only* way to get different-sized `em`s was through "primitive" font syntax, but merely that this one one possibility for obtaining different-sized ems. Thanks for also pointing out the effect that `\text{\quad}` vs `\quad` when encountering, say, a line break.

Comment: I tend to make special extra \text macros which has \quad, \qquad etc, build in, then the typographic spacing I'd like to have in my equations does not polute my code

Answer (score 11):

`\quad` is an hskip of 1em and its definition is the same in math and text mode, however there are many differences between the two uses you give. Notably `em` is a font dependent unit so the actual size depends on the fonts in use, but perhaps more importantly `\text` is a *box* command so the use inside `\text` is inside a box and will not be discarded at a line break:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{2cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent aaa aaa  $a + \text{\quad text\quad} b$

\noindent aaa aaa $a + \quad \text{text} \quad b$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A counterexample (?)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$a \text{\quad text\quad} b$\\
$a \quad \text{text} \quad b$

\font\meta=logo10 at 20pt
\noindent
\meta
{$A \text{\quad META\quad} M$\\
$A \quad \text{META} \quad M$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This example is not very natural, but shows that the answer is YES, if `em`'s are equal.

Comment: Ingenious. I've modified my answer to highlight the relevance of using a common font family (and at a common font size) in order for `\quad` to generate the same output in text and math mode.

Comment: This is because a font defined with `\font` doesn't obey LaTeX's rules; `\text` basically issues `\usefont{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{\f@series}{\f@shape}`, but since `\meta` doesn't change any of the `\f@...` macros, the result is almost unpredictable: in the outer level of the formula the current text font quad (`\meta`) is used, but not inside `\text`. Indeed you get `META` in the normal text font.